# What does mean here $\text{the vector space of its translations}$?

Tags: affine-geometry

The dimension of an affine space is defined as the dimension of the vector space of its translations.

What does mean here  $\text{the vector space of its translations}$?

We know that an affine space do not have fixed origin. In other word, in an affine space no vector has  a fixed origin and no vector can be uniquely associated to a point. Rather, in an affine space  there are concept of displacement vectors or translation vectors between two points in the space.

But I can not understand the line $\text{the vector space of its translations}$.

Someone please explain it if possible with examples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An affine space $S$ is a set of the  form $S=x+V$ where $x$ is a fixed vector and $V$ is a linear subspace. The dimension of this space is defined as dimension of $V$. ($V$ is a translate of $S$ because $V=\{-x+s: s\in S\}$).

Example: the  line $y=x+1$ is affine in $\mathbb R^{2}$ and is is a translate of the one dimensional  space $y=x$.

Comment: nice answer. I got it